# add filename column to file perl

Tags: windows, perl, while-loop, opendir

**My directory**

```
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
```

I am trying to capture each file name in a directory and print it to its coresponding file in an additional column along with some additional text and columns.

**TEST DATA**

```
hello,josh,12345,2014-10-30
```

**CODE**

```
my $directory = 'C:\directory';

opendir( DIR, $directory );
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
foreach (@files) {
    print $_, "\n";
}
while (<>) {
    #Do whatever here
    print;
}
```

**DESIRED RESULTS**

- 1.csv

  ```
  ID_1234,1.csv,Copmany,hello,josh,12345,2014-10-30
  ```
- 2.csv

  ```
  ID_1234,2.csv,Copmany,hello,josh,12345,2014-10-30
  ```

**CURRENT RESULTS**

```
.
..
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
hello,josh,12345,2014-10-30
```

---

I would also like to execute this one script on all files within the dir.

Comment: Where did `ID_1234` come from?

Comment: ID_1234 is an additional string of text that i want to concatenate my filename with

Comment: after you `opendir`, you should read twice and ignore the return value. You will always receive `.` and `..` in the first to reads. so read twice to skip them, then enter your while loop to process the actual files. Or, as somebody will undoubtedly point out use a file glob `glob('*.csv') to pattern match file anmes to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -i~ -F, -lane "BEGIN{$, =','; @ARGV=glob pop} print 'ID_1234',$ARGV,'Copmany',@F" *.csv
```

or

```
perl -i~ -pe "BEGIN{ @ARGV=glob pop} s|^|ID_1234,$ARGV,Copmany,|" *.csv
```

or

```
local $^I = "~";
local @ARGV = glob("C:\\directory\\*.csv");

while (<>) { 
  s|^|ID_1234,$ARGV,Copmany,|;
  print;
}
```

Comment: how do I add this into a program and implement into a while loop?

Comment: I went with @mpapec 's answer so I could use ARGV as a stored variable.  It worked wonders!  However instead of the regex posted above 's|^|ID_1234,$ARGV,Copmany,|;', I had one of my join fields = to ARGV, i.e. $flds[??]= $ARGV;  For the additional text I made a couple dummy columns.  I.e. $flds[??] =~ s/^.*?$/ID_1234/; and $flds[??] =~ s/^.*?$/Company/; Then you can join the fields to create that string of text.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
my $directory = 'C:\directory';

opendir( DIR, $directory );
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
foreach (@files) {
   print qq(ID_1234,$_,Copmany,hello,josh,12345,2014-10-30\n);
}
```